# how to add sticky toast notification in CI web application's ready state

Tags: php, jquery, css, codeigniter

How can we add sticky toast notification in codeigniter site. I need to load the sticky toast notification in the home page. how can we do this

i tried this. but its not working.

```
<div>

<p>
        <span class="description">Show a success toast</span> <a href="javascript:showSuccessToast();">not
        sticky</a>|<a href="javascript:showStickySuccessToast();">sticky</a>
    </p>

    <p>
        <span class="description">Show a notice toast</span> <a href="javascript:showNoticeToast();">not sticky</a>|<a
            href="javascript:showStickyNoticeToast();">sticky</a>
    </p>

    <p>
        <span class="description">Show a warning toast</span> <a href="javascript:showWarningToast();">not
        sticky</a>|<a href="javascript:showStickyWarningToast();">sticky</a>
    </p>

    <p>
        <span class="description">Show a error toast</span> <a href="javascript:showErrorToast();">not sticky</a>|<a
            href="javascript:showStickyErrorToast();">sticky</a>
    </p>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function showSuccessToast() {
        $().toastmessage('showSuccessToast', "Success Dialog which is fading away ...");
    }
    function showStickySuccessToast() {
        $().toastmessage('showToast', {
            text: 'Success Dialog which is sticky',
            sticky: true,
            position: 'top-right',
            type: 'success',
            closeText: '',
            close: function () {
                console.log("toast is closed ...");
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: What do your functions do? Have the elements any styles?

Answer (score 0):

Even i had some problem with toast message, so i did like this

**Html Code**

```
<div class="toast toast-default">
     <button class="toast-dismiss"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                Oops!!! Something went wrong while adding this product. Please try again after sometime.
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.toast-default {
    background: rgba(53, 164, 178, 0.8) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #fff;
}
.toast {
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: none;
    font-family: "ralewayregular";
    padding: 20px 10px 10px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 100px;
    width: 250px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Script Code

```
 $('.toast-default').fadeIn(400).delay(3000).fadeOut(400);
```

Call that script when ever you want to some toast message.